# How to find index of javascript array of object if value is given?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Here is my array of objects:

```
$scope.choices =  [
  {
     id: 0,
     product: [{id:'0'}] 
  }, 
  {
    id: 10,
    product: [{id:'5'}]
  }
];
```

How to find index number for id value "10"?

Answer (score 0):

Let following is the object you want to search in an array

```
var searchObject={
    id: 0,
    product: [{id:'0'}] 
};
```

Now using following

```
$scope.choices.indexOf(searchObject);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
var reqIndex;
$scope.choices.forEach(function(choice, index) {
    if (choice.id === 10) {
        reqIndex= index;
        return
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$scope.choices.findIndex(function(x) {
   return x.id==10;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you like to use pure javascript andno problem to use the you can use following

```
function findWithAttr(array, attr, value) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if(array[i][attr] === value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

findWithAttr(choices, 'id', 10);
```

Alternatively for angular you can use the following function

```
  $scope.findIndex=function(){

            angular.forEach( $scope.choices,function(object,index){
                     console.log(object);
                    if(object.id==10){
                        console.log('index'+index);
                    }


                })


        };
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to retrieve all the keys of you're object then iterate on them to find if there is one that has the corresponding value.